# Authentication from Android Client to Google App Engine Webapp2

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, webapp2

I have a web based application (Webapp2) with Google App Engine backend. The authentication is done using custom userid / password using the Webapp2 framework.

Now, I am extending this Web Application to Mobile using Android Client. How do I do authentication from Android Client to Google App Engine backend? Does Google Cloud Endpoints support custom userid / password authentication?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what the authentication is used for. Do you need users to authorize access to their data, or are you simply securing REST services provided to your application?

Cloud Endpoints uses OAuth 2.0 which can authenticate using Google Accounts, or you can also authorize against a "service account" for your app if user consent is not needed. A good source of information is the docs [1]. Of course, nothing is stopping you from implementing your own authentication scheme or using other libraries just as you would if you hosted your mobile backend on some other platform.

Another good doc specific to mobile authentication is 'Authenticating Users in Mobile Apps' at [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints
[2] https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps

Comment: I am using my own userid / password so cannot use Google Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get some inspiration from https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate

That is a huge topic to actually summarize :) But I will try my best.

First you should read about what is a OAUTH Client Flow and Server Flow.(You can decide which one to use.) Then I will use Facebook as an example.

Let's say you use Facebook SDK on Android to authenticate your user,  normally if they already authenticated in their facebook app, you will get UserID and AccessToken and some other information returned to you. This is facebook telling you:" Yes, you can trust this guy. Here is his id and information."

Then you could utilize that information to store in your own user database (or datastore in GAE jargon). So later you can tell who is who when they login with their specific ID tied to your user. (One user can have different provider ID.) Just remember that.

Now go back and look at the gae-boilerplate implementation: https://github.com/coto/gae-boilerplate/blob/master/bp_includes/handlers.py

Look at the three handler classes: LoginHandler, SocialLoginHandler, CallbackSocialLoginHandler

Comment: Beast - I read through the Readme files but cannot follow. I am new to Android / GAE development. Can you help summarize the steps involved in authentication from android client back to GAE (using webapp2). Just a high level summary bullet points on the flow?

Comment: That is a huge topic to actually summarize :)

Comment: I extended my answers, Jack. Have a look.